# How can i set the time for Image on_hold behaviour?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am using an image `on_hold` behaviour to do a task. i take a timer for that in that timer i set time for 5 seconds that if user hold that image for 5 seconds page will navigate. Now i want that only in case if user hold image for 5 seconds then page navigate not in any condition like for 1 second or 2 seconds user hold and after that remove .How can i set timer for image `on_hold` ?

```
Public mainpage()
{ 
    InitializeComponent();
    timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
    {
        var frame = App.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;
        frame.Navigate(new Uri("/Second Page.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        timer.Stop();
    };
}

private void Image_Hold(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{     
    // want to set timer here either for story board or for on_hod behaviour
    myStoryboard.Begin();
    NewMedia.Play();
    tick();
}

private void tick()
{
    counter--;
    if (counter <=0)
    {
        timer.Start();
        counter = 5;
    }
    else
    {
        counter = 5;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using combination of [ManipulationStarted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.manipulationstarted%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and [ManupulationCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.manipulationcompleted%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) events instead of `Hold` event. Set the `Timer` interval to be 5 seconds :

```
timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
```

Upon user start holding the image, start the `Timer` :

```
private void Image_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    myStoryboard.Begin();
    NewMedia.Play();
    timer.Start();
}
```

Then if user stop holding the image before 5 seconds elapsed, stop the `Timer` :

```
private void Image_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    timer.Stop();
}
```

Comment: I appreciated your answer. but i'm not getting my result, still it move after 5 secs either user hold or not.. i'm unable to use condition if user stop holding image before 5 secnds then timer stop. when i use manipulation completed it means that user move hold.plzz suggest

Comment: Don't understand the last part : "...it means that user move hold". I expect manipulation completed to be triggered when user stop holding no matter how long he has been holding (but if user holds more then 5 seconds, then `Tick` event will be executed before manipulation completed)

Comment: Yaa you are absolutely right. Tick event will get executed when counter will b 0 and counter will b 0 when user tap on image 5 times. so there is confusion. i want something like when user hold image for 5 seconds only in that condition timer get start.

Comment: This answer (updated a bit to avoid confusion) suggests a different approach. `Tick` event will be executed 5 seconds after user starts holding image by setting `Interval` to 5 s. And if user stops holding later on before 5 s elapsed, the timer will be stopped so that `Tick` event won't be executed. No need to manually count elapsed seconds...